# yields in koa routing

Tags: node.js, koa

I'm trying to figure out the use of yield in koa routing.

as an example,

```
router.get('/data', function *(next) {
    this.body = yield someData;
});
```

If I wanted to send a static file, I could use koa-send like so :-

```
router.get('/data', function *(next) {
    yield send(this, 'file.html');
});
```

However if i assign the 2nd yield to this.body, it doesnt work.

so what does

```
this.body = yield ...
```

actually mean and why don't I need to assign the 2nd yield to the body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you peek inside the koa-send library you'll notice [this](https://github.com/koajs/send/blob/master/index.js#L86):

```
ctx.body = fs.createReadStream(path);
```

Basically the library is assigning a stream to `this.body`, then when you were trying to assign what is returned by calling `yield send(this, 'file.html')`, which appears to be the file [path and name](https://github.com/koajs/send/blob/master/index.js#L88), you're breaking / overwriting what the library was trying to do.

Now if you'd like, you could choose to not use `koa-send` and instead just do this:

```
this.body = fs.createReadStream('file.html');
```

Getting to your specific question

```
this.body = yield ...
```

You call yield (inside generators) on Promise/thunk/generator returning functions that do something asynchronous, which pauses execution in the function until the asynchronous task(s) are completed, and then restarts the function when the result is available.

I made a screencast a while back on understanding JavaScript Generators that you might find helpful:

http://knowthen.com/episode-2-understanding-javascript-generators/